# Draft email created by VBA code returns undeliverable error

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I create an email draft using the following VBA Code in Excel (2014):

```
Sub Send_email()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = "myself@hotmail.com"
        .Subject = "test email"
        .HTMLBody = "Sample test body"
        .Save
    End With
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I open the saved email and send it manually, I receive an Undeliverable error message from System Administrator:

> "Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients."

If I use:

```
.Send
```

instead of

```
.Save
```

The email is sent (with no Undeliverable error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help.  I was able to resolve the issue for myself by adding a call to `OutMail.Recipients.ResolveAll()`.

VB.NET

```
Call OutMail.Recipients.ResolveAll
```

This solved the issue for me.  However, if you have a version of Outlook that does not support antivirus detection, you may get a message box prompting you that an external app is trying to access email addresses or something similar to this:

> a program is trying to access e-mail address information ...

If you get this, Google the phrase above to find many articles on how to resolve.  It has to do with trust settings in Outlook.

Comment: This is a great solution and SOLVED the problem I had. I did receive a prompt from Outlook '.. a program is trying to send email.." or similar to that with "Allow", " Deny" buttons. There was however an option to Allow for certain amount of time. I select 10 minutes and nor more prompts afterward for 10 minutes..Perfect. Thank you, Pat.

Answer (score 0):

i run you code AS IS from within excel, and it's working well.

When i open outlook i found the draft , flagged "the message has not been sent".

The email is saved in Drafts Folder of my Outlook, and i can view it in outlook.

I opened the draft email and sent it by pressing the sent button , and it is sent successfully.
i can't guess the problem , for i didn't find it :).
Review the setting of your email in outlook, you may find something.

Comment: Thank you Hassan. Not sure which setting to tweak. As an update, I tried again and when sending the draft email by clicking the Send button caused the Outlook to crash. :"(...

Comment: Try to make a diagnostics for the office including outlook. Start menu-> Microsoft office tools ->Microsoft Office Diagnostics.